# Computation of critical value in F-distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution

[image]

Hello there!

Is there a way to manually compute the critical value of f-distribution from this table for df1=df2=417?

It should be 1.21194

Thanks

Comment: It must be somewhere in between the 1 and the other 3 values in the lower right corner, or use R `qf(0.025, 417, 417, lower.tail = F)` which confirms your number